# How to do picking in modern OpenGL without gluUnProject?

Tags: opengl, opentk, mouse-picking

How do you convert screen coordinates to world coordinates in modern OpenGL without the use of gluUnProject?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901453/using-glms-unproject

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK - gluUnproject needs all the info supplied to it (modelview, projection, etc) and it only performs the matrix inversion calculation. So if you have those matrices, you could call gluUnproject or perform those calculations yourself.

The code below is taken from [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GluProject_and_gluUnProject_code) (copied over so that this answer still holds water if the link dies).

```
int glhUnProjectf(float winx, float winy, float winz, float *modelview, float *projection, int *viewport, float *objectCoordinate)
  {
      // Transformation matrices
      float m[16], A[16];
      float in[4], out[4];
      // Calculation for inverting a matrix, compute projection x modelview
      // and store in A[16]
      MultiplyMatrices4by4OpenGL_FLOAT(A, projection, modelview);
      // Now compute the inverse of matrix A
      if(glhInvertMatrixf2(A, m)==0)
         return 0;
      // Transformation of normalized coordinates between -1 and 1
      in[0]=(winx-(float)viewport[0])/(float)viewport[2]*2.0-1.0;
      in[1]=(winy-(float)viewport[1])/(float)viewport[3]*2.0-1.0;
      in[2]=2.0*winz-1.0;
      in[3]=1.0;
      // Objects coordinates
      MultiplyMatrixByVector4by4OpenGL_FLOAT(out, m, in);
      if(out[3]==0.0)
         return 0;
      out[3]=1.0/out[3];
      objectCoordinate[0]=out[0]*out[3];
      objectCoordinate[1]=out[1]*out[3];
      objectCoordinate[2]=out[2]*out[3];
      return 1;
  }

  void MultiplyMatrices4by4OpenGL_FLOAT(float *result, float *matrix1, float *matrix2)
  {
    result[0]=matrix1[0]*matrix2[0]+
      matrix1[4]*matrix2[1]+
      matrix1[8]*matrix2[2]+
      matrix1[12]*matrix2[3];
    result[4]=matrix1[0]*matrix2[4]+
      matrix1[4]*matrix2[5]+
      matrix1[8]*matrix2[6]+
      matrix1[12]*matrix2[7];
    result[8]=matrix1[0]*matrix2[8]+
      matrix1[4]*matrix2[9]+
      matrix1[8]*matrix2[10]+
      matrix1[12]*matrix2[11];
    result[12]=matrix1[0]*matrix2[12]+
      matrix1[4]*matrix2[13]+
      matrix1[8]*matrix2[14]+
      matrix1[12]*matrix2[15];
    result[1]=matrix1[1]*matrix2[0]+
      matrix1[5]*matrix2[1]+
      matrix1[9]*matrix2[2]+
      matrix1[13]*matrix2[3];
    result[5]=matrix1[1]*matrix2[4]+
      matrix1[5]*matrix2[5]+
      matrix1[9]*matrix2[6]+
      matrix1[13]*matrix2[7];
    result[9]=matrix1[1]*matrix2[8]+
      matrix1[5]*matrix2[9]+
      matrix1[9]*matrix2[10]+
      matrix1[13]*matrix2[11];
    result[13]=matrix1[1]*matrix2[12]+
      matrix1[5]*matrix2[13]+
      matrix1[9]*matrix2[14]+
      matrix1[13]*matrix2[15];
    result[2]=matrix1[2]*matrix2[0]+
      matrix1[6]*matrix2[1]+
      matrix1[10]*matrix2[2]+
      matrix1[14]*matrix2[3];
    result[6]=matrix1[2]*matrix2[4]+
      matrix1[6]*matrix2[5]+
      matrix1[10]*matrix2[6]+
      matrix1[14]*matrix2[7];
    result[10]=matrix1[2]*matrix2[8]+
      matrix1[6]*matrix2[9]+
      matrix1[10]*matrix2[10]+
      matrix1[14]*matrix2[11];
    result[14]=matrix1[2]*matrix2[12]+
      matrix1[6]*matrix2[13]+
      matrix1[10]*matrix2[14]+
      matrix1[14]*matrix2[15];
    result[3]=matrix1[3]*matrix2[0]+
      matrix1[7]*matrix2[1]+
      matrix1[11]*matrix2[2]+
      matrix1[15]*matrix2[3];
    result[7]=matrix1[3]*matrix2[4]+
      matrix1[7]*matrix2[5]+
      matrix1[11]*matrix2[6]+
      matrix1[15]*matrix2[7];
    result[11]=matrix1[3]*matrix2[8]+
      matrix1[7]*matrix2[9]+
      matrix1[11]*matrix2[10]+
      matrix1[15]*matrix2[11];
    result[15]=matrix1[3]*matrix2[12]+
      matrix1[7]*matrix2[13]+
      matrix1[11]*matrix2[14]+
      matrix1[15]*matrix2[15];
  }
```

Comment: +1 for the link because it contains the code needed by OP (and me).  The posted code, however, shows a replacement to `gluProject`, while the OP requested `gluUnProject`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that copy-pasta. Updated.