# How do I convert pixel coordinates to opengl coordinates In my 2d game that uses glm::ortho?

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, glm-math

I have been trying to figure out how to convert pixel coordinates to opengl coordinates so I can use the mouse in my game for some things, I have tried many things, and have failed each time, here is my code:

```
glm::mat4 anim;

glm::mat4 model;

model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(-camerax + temp_sprites[id].xpos, -cameray + temp_sprites[id].ypos, temp_sprites[id].zindex));


anim = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(0.0f), axis_y);

model *= glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(temp_sprites[id].width, temp_sprites[id].height, 0.0f));


glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(-50.0f * gaspect, 50.0f * gaspect, -50.0f, 50.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

mvp = projection * model * anim;


glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_mvp, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp));
```

Comment: This question is quite unclear; perhaps add some comments to your code that state what each part is supposed to do.

Comment: Its just mainly the glm::ortho line that im concerned about.  How would i convert the coordinates, with having a glm::ortho setup like I have in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the width and height of the surface in pixels in `surfaceWidth` and `surfaceHeight` and the pixel co-ordinates of the top-left corner (if not zero) in `topLeftX` and `topLeftY`.

Based on your ortho call, the boundaries are as follows:

```
float left = -50.0f * gaspect;
float right = 50.0f * gaspect;
float bottom = -50.0f;
float top = 50.0f;
```

If you have a pixel co-ordinate `mouseX`, `mouseY`, subtract the top-left corner and then compute the GL co-ordinates like this:

```
float x = (((mouseX - topLeftX) / surfaceWidth) * (right - left)) + left;
float y = (((mouseY - topLeftY) / surfaceHeight) * (bottom - top)) + top;
```

This assumes that mouseY increases going down the screen (OpenGL co-ordinates increase going up).

(This is for an identity model transform)

Comment: It seems, I still cant get it to work.  The code is giving me very weird values from that formula.  Am i using the formula right? heres my code:         float xx = (((x - 0) / 640) * (right - left)) + left;
 float yy = (((y - 0) / 480) * (bottom - top)) + top;

Comment: How exactly are you using the co-ordinates? Are you drawing a model at that position? The formula doesn't take the model and anim matrices into account so aside from a simple translation of a model to that position it won't work if you are applying other transforms, as I mentioned in the last note. it's just unprojecting the ortho matrix. Have a look at glm's unproject function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901453/using-glms-unproject